# i get error Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Tags: c#, class

please help me regarding " Invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration" error. i need to have class that contains get and set method for employee data

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for HandleEmployeeData
/// </summary>
public class HandleEmployeeData
{
    private int oracle_id;
    private String firstname;

   public String getFirstname();
    {
    return firstname;
    }

    public int getOracleID();
    {
       return oracle_id;

    }

    /*public HandleEmployeeData()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }*/

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove semicolon after  `public String getFirstname();` and `public int getOracleID();`

Comment: ohhhhh i didn't consider it !! Thank you!